# Update function will not update my INT row

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update my data but it will not update correct. It will set it to 0. The other fields are getting updated perfectly but only the row "dagprijs" is not updating to whats in the field for some reason

My update code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["Edit"])) {
       global $db;
       $kenteken = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Kenteken"]);
       $merk = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Merk"]);
       $type = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Type"]);
       $soort = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Soort"]);
       $omschrijving = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Omschrijving"]);
       $gps = htmlspecialchars($_POST["GPS"]);
       $dagprijs = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Dagprijs"]); 

        $sql3 = "UPDATE auto
        SET Kenteken=:kenteken, Merk=:merk, Type=:type, Soort=:soort, Omschrijving=:omschrijving, GPS=:gps, Dagprijs=:dagprijs
        WHERE Kenteken =:kenteken";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql3);
        $data = array("kenteken" => $kenteken, "merk" => $merk, "type" => $type, "soort" => $soort, "omschrijving" => $omschrijving, "gps" => $gps, "dagprijs" => $dagprijs);

        try {
            $stmt->execute($data);

        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } 
?>
```

The form (Modal)

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="modal fade" id="Pas<?php echo $results['Kenteken']?>" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Auto met kenteken: <?php echo " " .$results['Kenteken']?> aanpassen?</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="icon-box">
        </div>
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Kenteken.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Kenteken" value="<?php echo $results['Kenteken']; ?>">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Merk</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Merk" value="<?php echo $results['Merk']; ?>">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Type</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Type" value="<?php echo $results['Type']; ?>">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Soort</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Soort" value="<?php echo $results['Soort']; ?>">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Omschrijving</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Omschrijving" value="<?php echo $results['Omschrijving']; ?>">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">GPS</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="GPS" value="<?php echo $results['GPS']; ?>">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Dagprijs</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Dagrpijs" value="<?php echo $results['Dagprijs']; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Edit" style="float:left; background-color:orange; color:white;">Wijzigen</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[The database where you can see it will set it to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIZSu.png)

Comment: Have you checked that you get a nonzero value from your FORM / `<input>` tag? I see ` <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Dagrpijs"`, and that is a typo.

Comment: I think you mean **column**, not **row**.

Comment: You should turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, you would have seen a warning that the index doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you the same user as @thisistheoneandonlyway? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286341/trying-to-add-a-record-to-the-database with similar code and a typo in the same name.

Answer (score 2):

This Typing error Change your input name to "Dagprijs" as you are using it in PHP.

Wrong

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="Dagrpijs" value="<?php echo $results['Dagprijs']; ?>">
```

Right

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="Dagprijs" value="<?php echo $results['Dagprijs']; ?>">
```

Comment: Typos should just be closed with comments, don't bother posting full answers

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in (name=)

`<input type="number" class="form-control" name="Dagrpijs" value="<?php echo $results['Dagprijs']; ?>">`

it should be

`<input type="number" class="form-control" name="Dagprijs" value="<?php echo $results['Dagprijs']; ?>">`

Comment: This is the second question where he's misspelled that word.

Comment: Typos should just be closed with comments, don't bother posting full answers.